# Vectorize functions on regions of array Octave/ Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the following Octave code:

```
A = 1:100;
B = [20 40 60];
C = zeros(3,11);

for i = B,
    C(i,:) = A( (B(i) - 10) : B(i) );
end
```

Which extracts sub-arrays starting at specific indexes from a longer array.

I tried:

```
C = A(B - 10,B);
```

But this only returns the first sub-array.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
>> C = A( bsxfun( @plus, -10:0, B' ) );

C =

    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40
    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60
```

If you don't have `bsxfun` in octave, you can do this with `repmat`

```
C = A( repmat( -10:0, [3 1] ) + repmat( B', [1 11] ) );
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).